# Computing the tangent map using partial derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $\mu: G\times G \rightarrow G$ be a smooth map. I want to compute the tangent map $T_{(e,e)}\mu: T_{e}G\times T_{e}G\rightarrow T_{e}G$ of $\mu$.

In a proof in my notes they use the partial derivatives to compute the tangent map of $\mu$ given by $(x,y)\rightarrow xy$

Is there a general formula for this?  Reference?

Comment: What are your $ x $ and $ y $?